# Blocking referer on specific routes in Flask

Tags: routes, flask, http-referer

Is it possible to block a specific route (say `/data`) from referers external to the site itself in Flask ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.referrer` contains the referrer of the request, so you can just apply some logic based on that.

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template_string('''
        <a href="{{ url_for('data') }}">Correctly Referred</a>
    ''')

@app.route('/data')
def data():
    print request.referrer
    if request.referrer != 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/':
        return abort(403) # Forbidden
        # or maybe: return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return 'Woo!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I'm sure different browsers within OS's and devices helpfully do slightly odd things with the referrer, so it'd be worth having an look about for their idiosyncrasies.  Perhaps it would be nicer just to set a session value on their visit to your homepage/entry-route, then check that session value is set using a `before_request`, almost like an automatic login.

So if you wanted to protect all your pages, except your `home` route-- you could so something like:

```
@app.before_request
def check_session():
    print request.endpoint
    if not session.get("legit") and request.endpoint is not 'home':
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Then on your home route, just add a `session["legit"] = True`.  Now whenever a user visits the site, they'll either get redirected right back to home if they're new, or if the session is still active, they'll be able to see everything.  Kind of like a wireless hotspot in a hotel/cafe.

Comment: Thanks ! Since I use several devices for debugging I used the approach you suggested by auto login users passing by the entry-route. I have not been using `before_request` yet (still using JSON data instead of real db for now) so I do not see how it could improve the situation. I could use however a decorator on routes that I want to block but I am not sure this is what you meant by using `before_request`

Comment: Added an example with the `before_request` to protect everything except `home`